# getView from another Class

Tags: android, android-bitmap

Im trying to display an Image from another class to my current class.
I've been reading alot on questions on here as to how to do this.

From the error log, I gather that the context Im trying to pass is not "fetched" by the loading class and causing a Null Pointer..I've tried a ton of different variations, and approaches, too many to post here..so the code posted below is the cleanest and hopefully the easiest way to explain my approach..thanks in advance

The image "holder" class MyImage.java

```
  public class MyImage {

ImageView image3, image1;
    View image2;
    int right = R.id.image_holder;
    int wrong = R.drawable.ic_wrong;
  int layoutholder = R.id.layout_holder;
    Bitmap a;


   public View getView(Context context) {

     image1.setBackgroundResource(wrong);

    return getView(context);
    }
```

The TestLoadingImage.java class where Im trying to display the View

```
public class TestLoadingImage extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void myImageHandler (View view){

    MyImage image = new MyImage();
    View gView1 = image.getView(this);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_holder);
    layout.addView(gView1);

}

}
```

Here is my main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
        android:id="@+id/myimgbtn"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="myImageHandler"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="Image Handler Button"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/right"/>
   </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

This builds, but it crashes crashes when I press the button to display the view.

```
`03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):    at android.graph.MyImage.getView(MyImage.java:26)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.graph.TestLoadingImage.myImageHandler(TestLoadingImage.java:32)`
```

Entire Error log :

```
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     ... 11 more
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.graph.MyImage.getView(MyImage.java:26)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.graph.TestLoadingImage.myImageHandler(TestLoadingImage.java:32)
03-14 07:19:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Looks like `image1` is not initialized in `MyImage`. So it will throw NPE in `getView()`. You need to call `LayoutInflater.inflate(...)` at some point to load your xml into a View object. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#from(android.content.Context)

Comment: Always try to use a context in the class Constructor of your MyImage class; that will help the class know where you are.

Comment: @sulai thnx for the feedback and ur right, I have used LayoutInflater.inflate() before in other classes.  The reason Im stubbornly trying to get this approach to work without LayoutInglater is because in this achartengine project found here, http://www.mediafire.com/download/ce4b82a4w8q2rd0/GraphAChartEngine+R149.zip the author uses this approach to display a chart, he uses GraphicalView, which if I understand correctly is a component from the achartengine library. Im aware Im not using this import in my implementation, I just thought there would be be a way without having to inflate.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are seeing this pattern in that project. The pattern the author of that project uses is to generate an Intent, not a View.

Comment: Sry, Im basing my code on the changes the author explains here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCtgG9UwM1g He explains how to change from intent to GraphicalView, a component of achartengine library and not something Im implementing in my code..I was trying to use/find the equivalent of that(GraphicalView)..now Im starting to think that the achartengine.Graphical library import, probably inflates a view..

Comment: In that video, the [ChartFactory](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/src/org/achartengine/ChartFactory.java) is what is using the Context to instantiate the Views.

Comment: yeah so I saw `return ChartFactory.getPieChartView(context, series, renderer);`
and I thought that the equivalent of that would be something like `return getView(context);`or `return getView(image1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log shows a `NullPointerException` on line 26 of MyImage.java.
Though you didn't specify which line that is, the issue is almost certainly `image1.setBackgroundResource(wrong);`.

In your `MyImage` class, you never instantiate any of your Views. Thus `image1`, `image2`, and `image3` are all null. When you try to set the background resource of `image1`, you thus generate a `NullPointerException`. I'm not sure where you expect/want these Views to come from, but it isn't happening.

Though it isn't a problem right now because you are crashing before `getView()` returns, you will also have a problem with infinite recursion when due to `return getView(context);`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Yes line 26 refers to `image1.setBackgroundResource(wrong);` in class MyImage 
line 32 refers to `View gView1 = image.getView(this);` in class TestLoadImage. 
So Im not well versed on terminology, but if I understand "instantiating views" I normally do it like this 
`ImageVIew image1;` 
and on my onCreate() 
`image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_one);` 
Im expecting the View to come from main.xml `android:id="@+id/image_holder`

So I read up on infinite recursion, and I see how it would be a problem and possibly leads to an OutOfMemory exception?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the application context to MyImage:

```
MyImage image = new MyImage( getApplicationContext() );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button bt1 =m_activity.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

In the above example where view bt1 is from another class.you can access bt1 by using class instance and get the id.Now,do what ever you want do with bt1 instance.

Note: Make Sure bt1 is public in another class